# How to view pid of process listening on port using netstat on macOS?

Tags: macos, network, command-line

For *nix we can use

```
  netstat -anp
```

specifically the `-p` option. This is not supported on `macOS`. I also tried `-b` and `-o` which do not work. So how is this done on `macOS`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the -v option for verbose output. That will give, well, verbose results so you can filter a bit with -p  and then maybe pipe to grep for your port number. Something like this to find the process using TCP protocol on port 80:

`netstat -anv -p tcp | grep "*.80"`

Here's a helpful resource with other options: https://www.btaz.com/mac-os-x/find-the-process-listening-to-port-on-mac-os-x/